# Usando Case When com LeftJoin

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, case

Estou montando uma proc, mas dependendo do valor de um parâmetro, eu gostaria que o left join fosse diferente.
Tentei as querys abaixo:

Essa funciona, porem o `else` como `null` ou mesmo sem o `else`, se o parâmetro 
`COD_FORNECEDOR_FILTRO` estiver `null`, a query não retorna nada.

```
LEFT JOIN FORNECEDOR F
        ON F.ID_FORNECEDOR = T.ID_FORNECEDOR 
        AND F.COD_FORNECEDOR = 
        (CASE WHEN @COD_FORNECEDOR_FILTRO IS NOT NULL 
        THEN @COD_FORNECEDOR_FILTRO 
        ELSE NULL
        END)
```

Esta não funciona.

```
CASE WHEN COD_FORNECEDOR_FILTRO IS NOT NULL 
THEN LEFT JOIN FORNECEDOR F ON F.ID_FORNECEDOR = T.ID_FORNECEDOR AND F.COD_FORNECEDOR = @COD_FORNECEDOR_FILTRO
ELSE LEFT JOIN FORNECEDOR F ON F.ID_FORNECEDOR = T.ID_FORNECEDOR 
END
```

A ideia é que se o paramêtro tiver valor, tenha join com o campo `F.COD_FORNECEDOR` se não, apenas com o `F.ID_FORNECEDOR`

Não estou conseguindo fazer da maneira que gostaria. Podem me ajudar?

Comment: Qual banco de dados?

Comment: SqlServer......

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode usar o próprio campo `F.COD_FORNECEDOR` quando o valor for `null`.

```
LEFT JOIN FORNECEDOR F
        ON F.ID_FORNECEDOR = T.ID_FORNECEDOR 
        AND F.COD_FORNECEDOR = 
        (CASE WHEN @COD_FORNECEDOR_FILTRO IS NOT NULL 
        THEN @COD_FORNECEDOR_FILTRO 
        ELSE F.COD_FORNECEDOR
        END)
```

Comment: Valeu, funcionou certinho!