# Validar parâmetro para desconsiderar left join

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estou montando um select, mas dependendo do valor de um parâmetro vir (loja = 00000 - todas as lojas), eu gostaria de ignorar o trecho "AND p.loja = e.loja " no left join para que assim ele desconsidere o valor e liste todas as lojas.

Tentei algumas formas e não consegui :(

```
SELECT Isnull(d.idprocessoassinaturadigital, p.idprocessoassinaturadigital) AS 
   CodSequencia, 
   p.proposta                                                           AS 
   CodigoProposta, 
   p.empresa, 
   p.produto, 
   Isnull(d.idprocessoassinaturadigital, p.idprocessoassinaturadigital) AS 
   IdProcessoAssinaturaDigital, 
   p.statusassinatura 

   FROM   propostascredito p 
   LEFT JOIN proposta_ass_digital_multipla d 
          ON p.empresa = d.empresa 
             AND p.proposta = d.proposta 
   LEFT JOIN aprovacaoautomatica e 
          ON p.empresa = e.empresa 
             AND p.produto = e.produto 
             AND p.lojista = e.lojista 
             AND p.loja = e.loja 
    WHERE  p.empresa = '01'
```

Answer (score 2):

Olá!
Pode dar uma olhada na utilização do CASE com LEFT JOIN, conforme link abaixo:
[Usando Case When com LeftJoin](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/145939/usando-case-when-com-leftjoin)

Espero que te ajude.

Abs!